# Four LEDs on one switch blink irregularly

Tags: lighting

We have four LED lights wired to a single dimmer switch.  When the lights are on and on an irregular basis all four lights flash then return to being on.  Sometimes when turning on the switch the lights remain off.  Rocking the switch will then get the lights to turn on.

Comment: Is your dimmer rated for LED’s ? Many are not and the led load is not sufficient for the electronics so strange things happens, since the switch is not coming on and wiggling things makes it work a loose connection or a bad dimmer can be the problem.

Comment: What make and model is the dimmer, and what make and model are the LED bulbs?